# Spinner not working

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot seem to get this spinner to work.  Any help is appreciated.  I want this to display as the page is loading.

```css
.spinner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px; /* half width of the spinner gif */
    margin-top: -50px; /* half height of the spinner gif */
    text-align:center;
    z-index:1234;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100px; /* width of the spinner gif */
    height: 102px /* height of the spinner gif +2px to fix IE8 iss */
  }
```

```xhtml
<div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;">
<img id="img-spinner" src="https://www.cmfgroup.com/images/list-graphics/loader.gif?       Status=Temp&sfvrsn=2" alt="Loading"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#spinner").bind("ajaxSend", function() {
    $(this).show();
}).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
    $(this).hide();
}).bind("ajaxError", function() {
    $(this).hide();
});

 });
</script>
```

Nothing is displayed with the page is loading

Comment: Your tags are wrong, for one. Please edit your tags to include "html" "css" and "javascript" and you will get better responses. This is not a "Java" question.

Comment: Oh! @msrd0 just edited the tags I think !

Comment: can you try putting the style tag in an external style sheet ?

Comment: No I formatted your code, A4L edited the tags: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26468093/2

Comment: And I now putted the style tags in an external style sheet

Answer (score 1):

You may be binding this after the ajax call already happens. Have you tried just adding the ajax spinner as well in the ready function and see if it goes away when the script completes?

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#spinner").show();
    $("#spinner").bind("ajaxSend", function() {
        $(this).show();
    }).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
        $(this).hide();
    }).bind("ajaxError", function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) says (emphasis in the original):

> **As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxSend() method should only be attached to document.**

Therefore, you should write:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function() {
    $("#spinner").show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    $("#spinner").hide();
}).ajaxError(function() {
    $("#spinner").hide();
});
```